# meaning of "critcally analyse the relationship between a high level tolerance of ambiguity by a small business..."

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Critically analyze the relationship between a high level tolerance of ambiguity by  a small business owner and success or failure in the business.

What does this sentence mean?

Comment: Welcome!  We're going to need some context for this. Can you include the source of this quote along with which parts of it are particularly confusing to you?

Comment: it's part of my assignment. The part where it is confusing is whether i have to critically analyse the success part of a business or both .

Comment: You're not supposed to critically analyze the success, you're  supposed to critically analyze the ***relationship*** between (tolerance of ambiguity) and (success or failure).

Comment: Is this the full question or just part of it?

Comment: ...Peter Shor youve just answered my question!!

Comment: It means that the author is hiding something.

Comment: Fantastic example of an over-written sentence, you couldn't make it up .. it's like Douglas Adams Vogon poetry analysis!

Answer (score 1):

It may help to see what it's asking if you look at it this way:

> - Critically analyze the relationship between these two things:
>
>   1. High-level tolerance of ambiguity by a small business owner
>   2. Success or failure in the business.

Comment: you've just made it easier to understand...!